Using systemd + docker exec to manage processes within a single container
As of today, I have many systemd services where each of them runs a command using docker run. The same docker is used for all services.
I've noticed that each container that runs, takes about 0.7% of my RAM. So I thought maybe I can simply run one container and simply use docker exec to run processes on them.
It basically works. But when I tried to implement it using systemd services, I have the issue where if I need to restart one process, it doesn't actually stop the running one.
When I tried added -ti to the docker exec command, I got the error of Not a TTY device. I've also tried just -i and still no success. Without the -t the SIGINT won't be sent to the docker. With it - it throws an error.
Is there any way I can make this work?
Thanks :)
